# Changing route direction depends on the language selected

Tags: php, laravel

so this is my route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'],function(){
Route::get('/','Room_randring_welcom@function0')->name('post')->middleware('setLocale');});
```

for example, if I chose es in lang or any other language I want to go to

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'],function(){
Route::get('/','Room_randring_welcom@function1')->name('post')->middleware('setLocale');});
```

**so I can fetch data from another JSON file with another language **

Comment: Why would you use another controller action? This should be processed in the controller, not in the routes.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can do it by edit `RouteServiceProvider`, Tell me If you don't know how to do it.

Comment: Mohamed Gamal Eldin
 i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @SMI My controller looks like this. I need a condition that tells if lang,en selected read data from this JSON file else FR lang selected read data from the other JSON  file2. ``  ``class Room_randring_welcom extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
       
       
        $posts = file_get_contents(base_path('/storage/Rooms_Data.json'));
        $posts = json_decode($posts, true);
        
       $collection=collect($posts);
     
    
       return view('welcome',[

        'uniqueUserIds'=>$collection,
      
    ]);
    }
}````

Comment: BTW which laravel version you are using? @Marouane

Comment: Laravel Framework 7.30.4 @MohamedGamalEldin

Comment: @Marouane let me edit the answer, My answer works with 8.x.

Comment: Please check the answer, Tell me if anything is wrong or not clear. @Marouane

Comment: @Marouane english only! Even if you say thank you ;-)

Comment: @Marouane You are very welcome, I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by editing `RouteServiceProvider`, You will find it at `root-app/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

### For Laravel <= 7

```
public function map()
{

   $this->mapApiRoutes();

   $this->mapWebRoutes();

   $this->mapArRoutes(); // Add this line with local name or anything you want.
}

//add function with the new name in my case will be "mapArRoutes"

protected function mapArRoutes()
{

    Route::middleware('web')
       ->prefix('ar') // Here choose a local do you want
       ->namespace($this->namespace)
       ->group(base_path('routes/ar.php')); // any name do you want
}

// You will find a function called "mapWebRoutes", edit it.

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    // This is a default route you just need add perfix with anothoer local do you want
   Route::middleware('web')
      ->prefix('en') // for example i added en
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Then inside the routes folder/directory add the new file, as my example, it will be `ar.php`

add all routes to the file related to local.

### For Laravel >= 8

```
...
public function boot()
{
 $this->configureRateLimiting();

 $this->routes(function () {
    Route::prefix('api')
       ->middleware('api')
       ->namespace($this->namespace)
       ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));


    // Add this lines
    // Start
    Route::middleware('web')
       ->prefix('ar') // Here choose a local do you want
       ->namespace($this->namespace)
       ->group(base_path('routes/ar.php')); // any name do you want

    // This is a default route you just need add perfix with anothoer local do you want
    Route::middleware('web')
      ->prefix('en') // for example i added en
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    // End


 });
}
...
```

Hope this is clear.

That's all.